# Solrnet Payloads - exception when I add documents

Tags: solr, solrnet

I am trying to index a set of images from tags entered by users with associated weights. I am trying to use the weights entered as payloads. I followed this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/solrnet/PBOW23OzC_4) and created dictionary objects.

I am not sure where to add the delimited field `colors.Add(tag_name, (float)score);` or should it be `colors.Add("color_p", "tag_name |score");`

How do I use the dictionary object referred to in the post?

```
Dictionary<string, float> colors = new Dictionary<string, float>();
                            tags = TagUtils.GetTags(image, models["colors"]);
                            N = tags.TagNames.Count;
                            for (int n = 0; n < N; n++)
                            {
                                string tag_name = tags.TagNames[n];
                                int score = tags.Scores[n];
                                colors.Add(tag_name, (float)score);
                            }

                            docs_list.Add(new SolrDocument
                            {
                                _product_id = product_id,
                                _product_type = product_type,
                                _url = url,
                                _sku = sku,
                                _images = images.ToList<string>(),
                                _price = (float)price,
                                _name = name,
                                _color_p = colors,<--my payloads type field
                            });
```

My `schema.xml` looks like this:

```
<field name="color_p" type="payloads" indexed="true" stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>
```

and the definition looks like this:

```
  <fieldtype name="payloads" stored="false" indexed="true" class="solr.TextField" >
         <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
             <filter class="solr.DelimitedPayloadTokenFilterFactory" encoder="float" delimiter="|" />
        </analyzer>
    </fieldtype>
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer, hope it helps anyone else stuck like I was:

```
*Dictionary<string, float> colors = new Dictionary<string, float>();*
```

should actually be

```
Dictionary<string> colors = new Dictionary<string>();
```

and add as follows:

```
                                tags = colorTags.Result;
                                N = tags.TagNames.Count;
                                for (int n = 0; n < N; n++)
                                {
                                    string tag_name = tags.TagNames[n];
                                    int score = tags.Scores[n];
                                    if (score > 0)
                                        colors.Add(tag_name + "|" + score);
                                }
```